# How to find the input tags contained in a table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question regarding the find method.

I want to be able to identify the cell that contains the `input` tag.

my html is like

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> celll </td>
      <td> celll </td>
      <td> celll </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> celll </td>
      <td> <span><input type='text'></span> </td>
      <td> <span><input type='text'></span> </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

My Jquery

```
$('table').find('td').each(function(){
          if($(this).find("input").length){
             console.log('found')
          }
      })
```

My codes can't seem to find it. Any tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems to work for me... http://jsfiddle.net/wM2Tg/

Comment: "identify the cell" singular? or all cells?

Comment: .length basically needs an argument. if the input is there, then the length will be > 0. So if($(this).find("input").length > 0) would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `.find()` twice, just use it once and get the `.closest()` cell:

```
$('table').find('input').each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest('td');
    //do something with parent
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/kdL97/

Answer (score 0):

Just use: `$('table input').parents('td');`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aPjwE/

Comment: @Dom It does. Your jsfiddle doesn't use my code. See my jsfiddle edit.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 `$('table').find('input')` has a better performance than  `$('table input')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("table td:has(input)").each(...)
```

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/wM2Tg/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var cells = $('table').find('td');

$.each(cells, function(i){
  var that = $(this);
  var hasInput = that.find("input");
    if(hasInput.length > 0){
        console.log("td #" + i + " has an input sire.");
    }
});
```